# SQLite foreign key, on delete cascade, and SQLITE_CONSTRAINT

Tags: node.js, sqlite

**Overview**:
I have a parent / child table relationship where the child may contain 2:n records with FK's back to the parent. **When attempting to delete from the parent, I get a SQLITE_CONSTRAINT error**. This is unexpected as I have FK's enabled, have the child registered with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and a new enough SQLite version.

**However**: My child table *originally* did not have `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I added (and enabled FK's) after data had been added to parent/child. From there, I renamed the original child & created a new table with the constraint, and finally moved to the new table.

Table layout as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
    message_id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    area_tag                VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    message_uuid            VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
    reply_to_message_id     INTEGER,
    to_user_name            VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    from_user_name          VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    subject, /* FTS @ message_fts */
    message, /* FTS @ message_fts */
    modified_timestamp      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    view_count              INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    UNIQUE(message_uuid) 
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS message_by_area_tag_index
ON message (area_tag);

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_fts USING fts4 (
    content="message",
    subject,
    message
);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS message_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON message BEGIN
    DELETE FROM message_fts WHERE docid=old.rowid;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS message_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON message BEGIN
        DELETE FROM message_fts WHERE docid=old.rowid;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS message_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON message BEGIN
    INSERT INTO message_fts(docid, subject, message) VALUES(new.rowid, new.subject, new.message);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS message_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON message BEGIN
    INSERT INTO message_fts(docid, subject, message) VALUES(new.rowid, new.subject, new.message);
END;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_meta (
    message_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    meta_category   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    meta_name       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    meta_value      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(message_id, meta_category, meta_name, meta_value), 
    FOREIGN KEY(message_id) REFERENCES message(message_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

At startup, directly after attaching to the DB's I ensure FK's are enabled:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Other details:

- SQLite version: 3.7.17
- Access: [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)
- Exact error: `Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

<strike>Is this caused by the fact that I later added the constraint?</strike> (See Update 1)
**How do I fix this without losing data?**

**Update 1**:
I can confirm that only select messages (I believe, messages that were in message *before* `ON DELETE CASCADE` as added to message_meta) cause the constraint error. Others delete just fine and properly take out associated message_meta records.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that what you've shown is the current schema of the DB?

Comment: @CL: Yes. Please read the description: I added the ON DELETE CASCADE to message_meta after there was some data in message and message_meta. To do this, I had to rename the original, create a new table (using SQL above) then move the data in. I'm wondering if this borked it-- and if so, how to fix the situation.

Comment: Please show the values in both tables' row that are affected by the delete.

Comment: There are thousands of values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question -- after some hours of trying various things I was able to find the issue(s):

- When I originally added the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause, I did so by renaming the original `message_meta` table to `message_meta_backup`, creating a new table with the clause, then moving the data into it: `SELECT * FROM message_meta_backup INSERT INTO message_meta;`. What I *did not* do was to drop the backup table.
- Due to #1 or something related, something internal to my database became corrupted or confused.

**What I tried (that did not work):**

- `REINDEX;`
- Simply dropping the backup table: `DROP TABLE message_meta_backup;`
- ...and various other things I forget :)

**What DID work:**
What finally ended up working was a **combination of dropping the backup table and completely rebuilding the database** using the `sqlite3` shell's `.drop` command:

```
> sqlite3 db/message.sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> drop table message_meta_backup;
sqlite> .quit
> sqlite3 db/message.sqlite3 ".dump" >> message_dump.sql
rm db/message.sqlite3 
> cat message_dump.sql | sqlite3 db/message.sqlite3
```

I'm now able to `DELETE FROM message ...` and have it properly cascade the delete to `message_meta` without the nasty error:

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM message WHERE message_id IN(SELECT message_id FROM message WHERE area_tag='some_area' ORDER BY message_id desc limit -1 offset 200);
sqlite>
```

(no error given!)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when attempting to delete via the Db Browser for SQLite GUI.

When I ran the command from the sqlite shell, it worked with no problems DB Browser must be adding some unnecessary step.